# Convert JSON.STRINGIFY to json array length is not calculating

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

Hi i have excel upload functionality when i upload the excel that should save in to the mongodb(database). I have taken the excel cell value as json stringify and also i converted that as parse.  now i don't how to  get that json length value.

> here i have attached my code

```
    function to_json(workbook) {
    debugger;
    console.log(workbook);
        var result = {};
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
    $scope.Sheetname=sheetName;  // here sheet name is excel sheet name

        MainSheetName=sheetName;
            var roa = X.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
            if(roa.length > 0){
                result[sheetName] = roa;
            }
        });
        return result;

    }




    var HTMLOUT = document.getElementById('htmlout');
    function to_html(workbook) {
        HTMLOUT.innerHTML = "";
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
            var htmlstr = X.write(workbook, {sheet:sheetName, type:'binary', bookType:'html'});
            HTMLOUT.innerHTML += htmlstr;
        });
    }

    var tarea = document.getElementById('b64data');
    function b64it() {
        if(typeof console !== 'undefined') console.log("onload", new Date());
        var wb = X.read(tarea.value, {type: 'base64',WTF:wtf_mode});
        process_wb(wb);
    }
    window.b64it = b64it;

    var OUT = document.getElementById('out');
    var global_wb;
    function process_wb(wb) {
        global_wb = wb;
        var output = "";
        var output1 = "";
        switch(get_radio_value("format")) {

            case "json":
                output = JSON.stringify(to_json(wb), 2, 2);

                output1=JSON.parse(output);
                break;
            case "form":
                output = to_formulae(wb);
                break;
            case "html": return to_html(wb);
            default:
                output = to_csv(wb);
        }
        if(OUT.innerText === undefined) OUT.textContent = output;


        else OUT.innerText = output;
        debugger;

        $scope.MainInfo=output1;         // this return whole data
         console.log(output1);
        $scope.jsondata=output1.Sheet1[0].length;// this returns undefined. Here sheet name is excel file sheetName it will taken from excel.
console.log($scope.jsondata);
```

> my output is showing like this

```
{
  "Sheet1": [
    {
      "Name": "xxx",
      "Age": "22",
      "Salary": "222222"
    },
    {
      "Name": "yyy",
      "Age": "23",
      "Salary": "232323"
    },
    {
      "Name": "zzz",
      "Age": "23",
      "Salary": "232323"
    }
  ]
}
```

now  i want length of Sheet1 how can i get that. can any one tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to assign your output to `obj` getting the length of Sheet1 would be as simple as going `obj.Sheet1.length`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var output = {
    "Sheet1": [{
        "Name": "xxx",
        "Age": "22",
        "Salary": "222222"
    }, {
        "Name": "yyy",
        "Age": "23",
        "Salary": "232323"
    }, {
        "Name": "zzz",
        "Age": "23",
        "Salary": "232323"
    }]
};
var newArr = $.grep(output1.Sheet1, function( value, index ) {
    if(n.Name == "xxx") {
        return n;
    }
});
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: I am so confused, why are you overcomplicating it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular.fromJson(yourJson).length functionality.
In your case, it should be angular.fromJson($scope.jsondata).length.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding from above code, your are getting response into JSON string format so you can't perform JSON operation over it. try to convert json string to json object using JSON.parse method.Below is sample code in node js.

```
var parseData = JSON.parse(output1);
```

var parsedata1 = parseData.Sheet1;

```
for(var namevalue=0;namevalue<parsedata.length;namevalue++){
console.log("Name value: "+parsedata1[namevalue].Name);
```

}